# using triggers with firebase cloud function express architecture

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Is it possible to use triggers for both realtime database and firestore using using an express architecture for on firebase 9 cloud functions ? my triggers are not triggering I think because of the express setup.

firebase.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp();
// admin.database.enableLogging(true);

const firestore = admin.firestore;
const db = admin.database;
const auth = admin.auth;
const storage = admin.storage;

module.exports = { firestore, db, functions, auth, storage };
```

App.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
const { auth, resources } = require("./routes");

app.use("/v1/auth", auth);

// This is the Firebase HTTPS function
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  onUserCreate,
  register,
} = require("../controller");

router.post("/register", register);
//is this suppose to be here to be triggered?
module.exports = onUserCreate;


module.exports = router;
```

Register.js

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
 //do stuff
};
```

onUserCreate.js

```
exports.onUserCreate = functions.database
  .ref(`/users/{uid}`)
  .onCreate(async (user) => {
   //....do stuff when user is created

  });
```

or

```
 exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore
      .document(`/users/{uid}`)
      .onCreate(async (user) => {
       //....do stuff when user is created
    
      });
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are add a new document in the Realtime database or Firestore ?

Comment: I think the issue is you are using a / before the collection name (users) it should be exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore
      .document(`users/{uid}`)
      .onCreate(async (user) => {
       //....do stuff when user is created
    
      });
Firebase triggers happens irrespective of platform / codebase which which you are adding or modifying a Firestore document

Comment: You are facing issues for Firestore triggers only? as @Vaidhy mentioned for Firestore you should not use “/” before users in “exports.onUserCreate”. See [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) for firestore wildcard triggers. I think “/” is allowed in Realtime database triggers as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) but not in firestore triggers.

Comment: @obumoon @Frank van Puffelen what was the outcome of this question, I'm experiencing the same thing.  Is the recommendation to have a multiple ``index.ts`` files deploy to the same project?  Along the lines of this reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo

Comment: Any hints on how this should be addressed? I also picked up a codebase that has an express app with cloud functions in it. But no triggers, and there's no clear documentation as to how are triggers supposed to be registered in an express app